# Is there a way to render SVG in Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms, svg, rendering

I am working with a library that renders part of its state as an SVG document.

I would like to render this in either a Windows Forms or a WPF environment. Is there currently a way to do this?

If not, I could modify the library to use a more general rendering strategy, and then add an XML adapter to restore the original functionality, but this is not my preferred strategy.

Answer (score 9):

I have tried [SVG.NET](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) with WinForms and it works excellent.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the webbrowser control for SVG, you will have a problem with Access Violation due to Data Execution Prevention.

The workaround is to have the following lines in your post-build events

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\..\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\..\VC\bin\editbin.exe" /NXCOMPAT:NO "$(TargetPath)"
```

For additional information [see this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ed_maurer/2007/12/13/nxcompat-and-the-c-compiler/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Forms.WebBrowser with

> WebBrowser.Url = new Uri($"file://{pathSvg}");