# How to use SVG to create 2D Lines in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, svg

I need to create a Vector Graphics which contains Line,Circles, Text, Arrow Lines etc. These will be created using data from Database. Also, When clicked on particular item on Vector Graphics, it should highlight the same object on Tree View. (For example a section is present in tree view and is represented by arrow line. So if I click on arrow line on graphics, it should highlight section node present in tree view).
Also if I add some objects on tree view, it should be added on graphic image as well.
I have gone through many SVG tutorials and references but they were not of much help.
If anyone can help me with above query or is aware about how can this be achieved then please help.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you [seen this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484975/is-there-a-way-to-render-svg-in-windows-forms)? As for your other six requirements, you should try something and ask one question at a time for specific problems. I have a feeling this will be challenging in winforms.

Comment: Yes i have seen this but it does not help with the functionality we want.