# How to print svg string without file creation

Tags: c#, winforms, svg

I generated svg strings in my program c#. How can I print svg strings without file creation?

Comment: See if this answers your question maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484975/is-there-a-way-to-render-svg-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 1):

A simple example using a WebBrowser class.
You can of course use a WebBorwser Control, if you also need to show the SVG on screen.
You can do the same with a WebView2 Control / CoreWebView2 object.

Using a bare-bone HTML5 document text, set the content of an `IMG` element to the SVG string converted to base64, setting the mime-type of the data to `image/svg+xml`.
The `Width` of the IMG element is set to `200` (~2 inches, ~50 millimeters).
Modify as required (considering the DPI, if necessary).

Then create a WebBrowser class, generate a [new empty Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.opennew) object and [Write()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.write) to it the HTML content (using this method to have immediate rendering of the content).
After that, call the [WebBrowser.Print()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.print) method to send the rendered SVG to the default Printer.

Assume `svgContent` is your SVG string:

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(svgContent);
int svgWidth = 200;

string html = $"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>" +
    $"<img width={svgWidth} src=\"data:image/svg+xml;base64,{base64}\"/>" +
    "</body></html>";

var wb = new WebBrowser() {ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true };
try {
    wb.Navigate("");
    var doc = wb.Document.OpenNew(true);
    doc.Write(html);
    wb.Print();
}
finally {
    wb.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place `<svg>whatever</svg>` tags [directly inline into your html5 document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web#how_to_include_svg_code_inside_your_html) as text. When a browser receives that document it renders the svg in `whatever`.  This is a double-cool way to do it because your CSS applies to your svg elements.

Here's a [decent introduction](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/use-svg-images-in-css-html/). Look for the section on how to use inline svg.

Comment: Hmm, this is actually useful information and can be applied here.